# Solr join query with foreign field sorting not working

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm trying to retrieve the users which is blocked by me using solr join.
But, I'm unable to find the documentation for sorting using foreign field.

It should be helpful if someone guide me to sort based on the join createdAt field.

Most of them suggested to use score with join. As a beginner I was not able to do sorting but tried below query with score max. Result is not in sort order.

```js
/users/query?q=*
&fl=*
&fq={!join from=blockedId fromIndex=blocked to=id score=max}blockedBy:12  {!func}createdAt
&sort=score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question

Finally, Below solr query helped me to sort the documents using join query foreign field :-)

```js
/users/query?q={!join from=blockedId fromIndex=blocked to=id v='{!boost b=$recency v=$qq}' score=max}
&fl=*
&recency=recip(ms(NOW,createdAt),3.16e-11,1,1)
&qq=blockedBy:12
&sort=score desc
```